# Select combination of two columns, and count occurrences of this combination

Tags: mysql, sql, django-views

I have a table with questions, where each row is a question and all questions has a asked_by and answered_by field. I want to select all unique combinations of "askers" and "answerers" and count how many times this combination of asking/answering have occurred.

```
question_tbl:

id      | asked_by | answered_by | session
--------+----------+-------------+---------
1       | AA       | JD          | 2011-2012
2       | JD       | AA          | 2011-2012
9       | AA       | JD          | 2011-2012
12      | AA       | JD          | 2009-2010
```

I want to return the unique combinations in in session, and the count for this combination.

E.g. for 2011-2012:

```
AA, JD, 2
JD, AA, 1
```

PS: Ideally I'd write this for the django orm, but as I can't even seem to figure out how to formulate a sensible google search for this, to find the SQL-way is my goal.

**Note after problem was solved:**
As this turned out to be quite easy in SQL, it turned out to be quite easy in Djangos ORM too. I'll leave it here for later record:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from myproject.models import Questions

Questions.objects.filter(sesjonid='2011-2012').values('sporsmal_til', 'sporsmal_fra').annotate(count=Count('besvart_av'))
```

By testing how that looks in SQL it seems to me to correct (in the ./manage.py shell):

```
print str(Questions.objects.filter(sesjonid='2011-2012').values('sporsmal_til', 'sporsmal_fra').annotate(count=Count('sporsmal_til')).query)
```

This prints SQL that does exactly the same as Bohemians'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A straightforward `COUNT(*)` with a `GROUP BY` will do it:

```
select asked_by, answered_by, count(*)
from question_tbl
where session = '2011-2012'
group by 1, 2;
```

If you wanted a query to return data for *all* sessions, use this:

```
select session, asked_by, answered_by, count(*)
from question_tbl
group by 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm almost embarrassed it can be done that easily, but I'm very grateful for the help - I was stuck.

Comment: Accepted! (I was figuring out how to translate this into django orm code, thought the question would be complete if I could figure out that and add it.)